# Any suggestion on following memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsoperationqueue

I am developing application using NSOPerationqueue. It shows me leak when add OperationBlock in queue as i shown below in image. Please help me to find out leak resolution. If you need more screen shot or detail than please let me know.

You can also see my code in image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if your [self parsing:tempdata:aregion] retains the aregion string the you must release the aregion string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using stringWithFormat you can use
NSString *aregion = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@""];

// your operations

[aregion release];